# android studio load text from url and split by delimeter

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, url

i am trying to get text from url

the text is in this format :

```
text1:text2:text3:text4
```

after i need to split by delimeted ":" and
i need to run foreach command
MyFunction(string[i])

any help will be appreaciated

Answer (score 1):

```
val textList = rawUrl.split(‘:’)
textList.forEach { }
```

Comment: how to read text from URL

Comment: Can you clarify the full input and output you need?